# Vector Subscript out of Range. Comparing Elements of Vectors

Tags: c++

So I have a vector like this

```
All_Pos={0,10,15,24,30,33,66}
```

And three smaller vectors that contain the numbers from the previous vector, let's say

```
Vec_Lin={0,15}
Vec_Circ={24,33,66}
Vec_Arc={10,30}
```

I want to make something like this:

```
All_Pos[0]=Vec_Lin[0]? YES -> Do something

All_Pos[1]=Vec_Lin[1]?No 

All_Pos[1]=Vec_Circ[0]?No

All_Pos[1]=Vec_Arc[0]?Yes -> Do Something
```

Ans so on, until i finish my All_Pos. The problem is that i get vector out of range and i don't know how to fix that.

```
int counter_linie=0;     
int counter_cerc=0;     
int counter_arc=0;

 for (int p = 0; p < All_pos.size(); p++)
 {      
    if(All_pos[p] == Vec_Lin[counter_linie])
    {
        //Do something

        counter_linie++;
    }

    if (All_pos[p] == Vec_circ[counter_cerc])
    {

      //Do something
        counter_cerc++;
    }

    if (All_pos[p] == Vec_Arc[counter_arc])
    {
        /Do something
        counter_arc++;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check for out of range. [] operator works ,when indexing is in limits from '0' to vector.size().

```
void process_vector(void)
{
    std::vector<int> All_Pos = { 0,10,15,24,30,33,66 };
    std::vector<int> Vec_Lin = { 0,15 };

    std::vector<int>    Vec_Circ = { 24,33,66 };

    std::vector<int>    Vec_Arc = { 10,30 };

    int counter_linie = 0;

    int counter_cerc = 0;

    int counter_arc = 0;
    for (int p = 0; p < All_Pos.size(); p++) {

        if (counter_linie< Vec_Lin .size() &&  All_Pos[p] == Vec_Lin[counter_linie])
        {
            //Do something

            counter_linie++;
        }

        if (counter_cerc < Vec_Circ.size() &&  All_Pos[p] == Vec_Circ[counter_cerc])
        {

            //Do something
            counter_cerc++;
        }

        if (counter_arc < Vec_Arc.size() &&  All_Pos[p] == Vec_Arc[counter_arc])
        {
            // Do something
            counter_arc++;
        }


    }
    std::cout << counter_linie << " " << counter_cerc << " " << counter_arc << std::endl; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access elements that don't exist in your smaller vectors.

`Vec_circ` can only be accessed with indices 0, 1 and 2, but after three successful checks for `Vec_circ` in your loop `counter_cerc` will be 3. 
Trying to access `Vec_circ[3]` then leads to the error.

You need a mechanism that prevents this case.

Answer (score 1):

You should step through your code with a debugger to see the problem.

Initially the values are:

```
int counter_linie=0;
int counter_cerc=0;
int counter_arc=0;
```

After the first iteration the values are:

```
counter_linie=1;
counter_cerc=0;
counter_arc=0;
```

After the second iteration the values are:

```
counter_linie=1;
counter_cerc=0;
counter_arc=1;
```

After the third iteration the values are:

```
counter_linie=2;
counter_cerc=0;
counter_arc=1;
```

And now you try to read

```
Vec_Lin[2]
```

in

```
if(All_pos[p] == Vec_Lin[counter_linie])
```

That's your problem. Add a check into the if conditions.

```
if(counter_linie < Vec_Lin.size() && All_pos[p] == Vec_Lin[counter_linie])
```